# Specific TFS queries in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have some queries that I would like to run on work items within TFS, however the build in fields are too restrictive.
Is there a short cut within TFS where I can run a SQL type query?

Comment: No, you would have to create a [WIQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130198%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) query or use the API and process them all.